What is the member name of value stored in an Rc<T> pointer?
I am reviewing the implementation of Deref for Rust, and was curious as to what is the member name that is returned in the call to fn deref(&self) for Rc<T>:
impl<T> Deref for Rc<T> {
    type Target = T;
    fn deref(&self) -> &T {
        &self.<Rc member name>
    }
}

What is "Rc member name"?
I looked here but was unable to locate it.

I am open to receiving a downvote if my question is ill-formed or clearly asked in other questions.
If anyone has any idea as to why this was downvoted, please let me know so that I can keep that in mind for my next question.

When you need to look up the implementation, you can always use source link in the documentation. In this specific case, it will be the link on impl Deref for Rc, which leads to this code:
impl<T: ?Sized, A: Allocator> Deref for Rc<T, A> {
    type Target = T;

    #[inline(always)]
    fn deref(&self) -> &T {
        &self.inner().value
    }
}

And inner is a non-public function, so it's not in the documentation, but searching the same source file yields this:
impl<T: ?Sized, A: Allocator> Rc<T, A> {
    #[inline(always)]
    fn inner(&self) -> &RcBox<T> {
        // This unsafety is ok because while this Rc is alive we're guaranteed
        // that the inner pointer is valid.
        unsafe { self.ptr.as_ref() }
    }
}

